# ComponentContainer in dialog with routing

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a application where I want to open a complete component with the **sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer**

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
    <Dialog title="Test" class="sapUiNoContentPadding" placement="Auto" contentHeight="700px" contentWidth="700px">
        <content>
            <core:ComponentContainer name="my.other.component" />
        </content>
    </Dialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

This works fine for components without **routing**. If I want to add routing to the component the dialog closes automatically, because it uses the *controlId* of the main application.

Is there any way to implement this with the routing enabled? And if I close the dialog that the old routing is used?

Comment: Why do you need routing in a Dialog?

Comment: I want to add a view from another application, or is there any other way to archieve this? Because I load something to the view in the attachPatternMatched method.

Answer (score 0):

There is a property in sap.m.Dialog.js which default value is true and close a dialog when navigating. The property is closeOnNavigation. You should set it to false

```js
/**
* Indicates whether the Dialog will be closed automatically when a routing navigation occurs.
* @since 1.72
*/
closeOnNavigation: {type: "boolean", group: "Behavior", defaultValue: true}
```

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/Dialog.js

Kind regards,
Nau